# 404 Not Found nginx/1.19.0 istio spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

I tried to add reactjs on the frontend and spring boot on the back and for some reason I get the following error will trying to add both on Kubernetes with Istio installed on top in AWS.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: user-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: userhub-app
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - developer-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
        - uri:
            exact: /api/v1/users
      route:
        - destination:
            host: userhub-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here is also the yaml file for the for the spring boot

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    appdb: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      appdb: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        appdb: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:3.6.6
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    appdb: mongodb
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: users
  labels:
    app: users
    service: users
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: http
  selector:
    app: users
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: users
  labels:
    account: users
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: users-v1
  labels:
    app: users
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: user-hub
      containers:
        - name: ratings
          image: docker87/users
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: MONGODB_HOST
              value: mongodb
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
```

Here is the yaml file for the react app

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: users-app
  labels:
    app: users-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
  selector:
    app: users-app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: users-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: users-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: users-app
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-app
          image: docker87/client
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

When I deploy the react app to Istio I see the app, but when I try to deploy the spring boot backend I get an 404 Nginx error any idea what I could be doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with fixing your gateway and virtual service as it´s not properly configured.

Things to change:

- virtual service gateways must match gateway name
- virtual service route.destination.host should match your service name.

So it would look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: user-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: userhub-app
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - user-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
        - uri:
            exact: /api/v1/users
      route:
        - destination:
            host: users-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

After this change you should be able to use your ingress-gateway loadBalancer IP to enter it, for example with curl.

```
curl -v ingress-gateway-ip/
```

---

Additionally I would suggest to take a look how istio [bookinfo example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) works, it might help with understading how it works.